# How to disable test name too long warnings?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I'm using xUnit Theory and an [AutoMoqData](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/) attribute to generate test values, and this is causing test functions signatures to be very long apparently. The test explorer only shows the test function names, but in the console output I see a lot of these:

> Contents of string 'test name ...' exceeds max of '449', string has
>   been truncated.

They might hide other more important warnings, is there a way to prevent these from appearing?

Example test:

```
[<Theory; AutoMoqData>]
member this.``test name bla bla bla`` logger uri credentials jsonString = 
    ...
```

Comment: One thing to find out is is who generates that warning - xUnit, the runner, Visual Studio, AutoFixture?

Comment: Seems to be VS https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-vs-adapter/+bug/1065462

Comment: I would say that thread also has the answer - letting the errors occur and suppressing the warnings (if possible at all) can apparently cause subsequent tests not to be run, which likely is not what you want. The better way to proceed appears to be finding out what exactly causes the strings to be that long and making sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: Only with NUnit - I use xUnit and so far no issues except seeing the warnings in the console. I could of course convert the parameters to local variables and "manually" create them but I'm looking for a solution that preserves the use of Theory/AutoMoqData.